# How to swap link with data value with javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexof

How do I swap this:

```
var message = 'Another hurricane is coming <a contenteditable="false" data-number="23">here</a>. And check out pictures <a contenteditable="false" data-number="43">over there</a>.';
```

Into this:

```
message = 'Another hurricane is coming @[23]. And check out pictures @[43].';
```

What I have so far:

```
var swap = function(message) {
  message.each(function() {
    var text = '@[' + $(this).data(number) + ']';
    message = $(this).replaceWith(text);
  });
  return message;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that you should use `'` for the outer ones because you already use `"` inside the string

Comment: ok changed, although it doesn't make a difference on the code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tiny regular expression could fix that for you:

```
message = message.replace(/<a contenteditable="false" data-number="(\d+)">.+?<\/a>/g, '@[$1]');
```

Or as the required function:

```
var swap = function (message) {
    return message.replace(/<a contenteditable="false" data-number="(\d+)">.+?<\/a>/g, '@[$1]');
}
```

---

### A more flexible/dynamic version

```
message = message.replace(/<a.+?data-number=(?:"|')(\d+)(?:"|').+?<\/a>/g, '@[$1]');
```

This will work with any amount of attributes of `<a>` and even accept digits from both `data-number=""` and `data-number=''`. Doesn't get more flexible than that. Or does it? :-)

Comment: what about if contenteditable="false" is added? (forgot to add earlier) please see above edit.

Comment: Yeah the code is now updated to suit the `contenteditable="false"` addition.

Comment: And what if the text within the link is different? See above (once "here", and once "over there")

Comment: No problem, it should work with any text within the a tag now.

Comment: This code isn't dynamic at all. What if there's different HTML attributes ?!

Comment: What if there's not? Unless it's required, one line of pure JavaScript is better than a jQuery function in my book. Obviously, if it required, you should use a more dynamic jQuery solution.

Comment: I just found out that these Regex don't work in Firefox, although they work fine in Chrome. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp *disconnected* element and use jQuery selectors to manipulate the HTML in a structured way. This has no DOM overhead and makes processing the HTML very convenient. It will also work if the attributes on the anchors ever differ from the example shown *as it does not try to exact match*:

Final shorter function version now brought to the top:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xbm2h6aL/5/

```
var swap = function (message) {
    var element = $('<div>').html(message);
    var $anchors = element.find('a').each(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith("@[" + $(this).data('number') + "]");
    });
    return element.html();
}
```

---

*Older versions below:*

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xbm2h6aL/1/

Note: the display div was purely for testing purposes, to show it worked.

```
var message = 'Another hurricane is coming <a contenteditable="false" data-number="23">here</a>. And check out pictures <a contenteditable="false" data-number="43">here</a>.'

// create a disconnected div with the content
var element = $('<div>').html(message);

var $anchors = element.find('a');
$anchors.each(function(){
    var $a = $(this);
    var n = $a.data('number');
    $a.replaceWith("@[" + n + "]");
});
$('#result').append(element.contents());
```

*The code can be shortened by a line or two, but I wanted it to be instructional :)*

**As a function (like the original):** http://jsfiddle.net/xbm2h6aL/3/

```
var message = 'Another hurricane is coming <a contenteditable="false" data-number="23">here</a>. And check out pictures <a contenteditable="false" data-number="43">here</a>.'

var swap = function (message) {
    // create a disconnected div with the content
    var element = $('<div>').html(message);
    var $anchors = element.find('a');
    $anchors.each(function () {
        var $a = $(this);
        var n = $a.data('number');
        $a.replaceWith("@[" + n + "]");
    });
    return element.html();
}

$('#result').append(swap(message));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var message = 'Another hurricane is coming <a contenteditable="false" data-number="23">here</a>. And check out pictures <a contenteditable="false" data-number="43">over there</a>.';
var swap = function(message) {
  var msg = $.parseHTML(message)
  , message = msg[0].textContent 
        + "@[" + msg[1].dataset.number + "]" 
        + msg[2].textContent 
        + "@[" + msg[3].dataset.number + "]";
  return message
};
```

```js
var message = 'Another hurricane is coming <a contenteditable="false" data-number="23">here</a>. And check out pictures <a contenteditable="false" data-number="43">over there</a>.';
var swap = function(message) {
  var msg = $.parseHTML(message)
  , message = msg[0].textContent 
        + "@[" + msg[1].dataset.number + "]" 
        + msg[2].textContent 
        + "@[" + msg[3].dataset.number + "]";
  return message
}; var _message = swap(message); document.write(_message)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a code using jQuery native functions and without RegExp:

```
var message = 'Another hurricane is coming <a data-number="23">here</a>. And check out pictures <a data-number="43">here</a>.';
var swap = function(msg){
    var html = jQuery.parseHTML(msg);
    var result = '';
    $.each(html, function(i, el){
        var element = $(el).filter('a');
        if(element.length > 0){
            var number = element.data('number');
            var text = '@[' + number + ']';
            result += text;
        } else {
            result += $(el).text();  
        }
    });
    return result;
}
swap(message);
```

You shouldn't rely on RegExp because you might have several attributes for the HTML elements you're using.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g3k3ovd4/

Comment: Overly complex version of the same technique I used (and just plain rude to down-vote two working answers) :P The text on the down-vote clear states "THIS ANSWER IS NOT USEFUL". Clearly both answers *were/are* useful.

Comment: It's not overly-complex. If `contenteditable` is equal to `true` the answer of @pimmey won't work. Your solution relies on saving data in the DOM, while it's not needed at all.

Comment: Creating a disconnected element *adds nothing to the DOM*. Please ensure you know what you are talking about before commenting again.

Comment: You're really acting in a childish manner. I down-voted this answer once because the solution isn't appropriate. I have no idea who down-voted you again but he also has the right to do so if he feels that your answer is inappropriate.

Comment: Unlike your good self, they appear to have realised their mistake and retracted that down-vote. If you go around down-voting valid answers out of ignorance, do not expect politeness in response.